# Fundamental group of theAlexandroff compactification of a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactness, fundamental-groups, compactification

> Consider $\mathbb R^2$ with the euclidean topology and let $X=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x^3-y=0\}$ be a subspace of the real plane.
> (a) Is $X$ connected, locally compact and closed?
> (b) Calculate the fundamental group of the compactification $\hat X=X\cup \{\infty\}$ with base point in $(0,0)$.

For the request (a) I had no problems, but I'm not sure about how approaching the second point of the exercise.
I'm used to computing fundamental groups (using van Kampen's theorems or via homotopic equivalence) of topological spaces like the torus , the Klein bottle, particular surfaces in $\mathbb R^2$ or in $\mathbb R^3$ and so on. I always worked with Alexandroff compactification showing, for example, certain topological properties of generic $\hat X$ spaces.
In this problem we have to compute the fundamental group of the compactification of $\Gamma_{y=x^3}$ and I'm not able (maybe it's easy) to visualize it, so I have difficulties in identifying the classes of homotopy of the loop that generate the topological space.

Thank for you for your help.

Comment: Have you made a drawing of what this space will look like?

Comment: No, but I'm sure it could help a lot.

Comment: HINT: $X$ is homeomorphic to a **very** familiar space.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think we can deform the space $X$ to the y-axis (?)

Comment: @Alchemist: Yes, or the $x$-axis, or simply $\Bbb R$.

Comment: In this case we have $\pi_1(X)\cong \pi_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb Z$  (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Your question has been answered in the comments. The space $X$ is the graph of the function  $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f(x) = x^3$. Thus $X \approx \mathbb R$.

(a) Yes.

(b) $\hat X  \approx S^1$, thus $\pi_1(\hat X) \approx \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Can we say that the quotient space $X/\{(1,1),(-1,-1)\}$ (we are identifying the points $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$) has the same homotopy type of $\hat X$?

Comment: I've already answered my own question in the comments with the help of Brian M. Scott but anyway thank you for you answer!

Comment: Yes, your quotient space is homeomorphic to $S^1$ with two half-open intervals attached to it. Or, what is the same, the wedge of a line and a circle.